# How to align a Division to the right

Tags: html, division

I am trying to push my sidebar to the right of my page. When I do this my division gets pushed to the bottom of the page. Why is this?

Here is my page:
[link text](http://www.akorra.com)

Comment: Sound like a `float` issue. Please post some code here. What is "push" (used twice)? What are you doing?

Comment: Which `<div>` is being "pushed"? Which browsers exhibit the behavior? Screenshots are in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because You use something like

```
    <div id="Main">
           <div id="content"></div><div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
```

note that Div is a Block element.
You have 2 option to correct this issue. use from an inline element like span (instead of content andsidebar ) or convert div to an in-line element with css like

```
 #sidebar, #content
 {
      display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: I think that whatever you said after "an inline element like" got interpreted as HTML by StackOverflow and doesn't show up. <span> maybe?